# How to create INT field (not a primary key) who start at 1000 with auto_increment

Tags: mysql, database, field, primary-key

I want to create a field `INT(11)` in my MYSQL Database who start at the value of 1000 and is incremented of 1 after each `INSERT`.

**WARNING: THIS IS NOT A PRIMARY KEY**

The DB is running with MYSQL 6.0 and InnoDB engine

**Who can I achieve this, if it's possible ?**

Comment: Do you want to make sure each number is unique? If yes why don't you set it as your primary key, you can still have a unique index on another column if you like. If no, I'm afraid there is not much you can do, there is no notion of auto incrementation of something that is not guaranteed to be unique.

Comment: Yes, each number must be unique. I can't set it as primary key because a primary key already exist and this field haven't the same sense as the primary key

Comment: is the primary key auto increment?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can have an auto_increment column as long as it is defined as a key (it doesn't have to be a `PRIMARY KEY`). So for example:

```
CREATE TABLE auto_inc_test (
    ID INT PRIMARY KEY,
    IncValue INT AUTO_INCREMENT,
    SomeData VARCHAR(50),
    INDEX(IncValue)
);
ALTER TABLE auto_inc_test AUTO_INCREMENT = 1000;
```

(The `ALTER TABLE` line sets the next value for the `AUTO_INCREMENT`.)

If you then run the following insert (which, obviously, gives no value for the IncValue field):

```
INSERT INTO auto_inc_test (ID, SomeData) 
VALUES (1, 'test 1'), (2, 'test 2'), (3, 'test3')
```

You'll get:

```
ID    IncValue    SomeData
1     1000        test 1
2     1001        test 2
3     1002        test 3
```

Comment: This is exactly what i want, but how can I set the primary key as an AUTO_INCREMENT field ?

Comment: You can't: You can only have one auto_increment column per table.

Comment: You can, as far as I'm aware, only have one `AUTO_INCREMENT` in a table. If you need two you're going to have to manage one of them manually - maybe using a trigger?

Answer (score 0):

Try below code hope this should help you focus on the syntax part in below code -- KEY (id) --

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `users`(
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `username` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `password` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `email` varchar(80) NOT NULL,
  `type` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `created` datetime NOT NULL,
  `modified` datetime NOT NULL,
  `status` enum('1','0') NOT NULL COMMENT '''0'' for inactive ''1'' for active',
   PRIMARY KEY (`username`),
   KEY (id)    
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=1000;
```